# How do I load ShapeFiles in firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Im trying to load shape files to show world borders on this sphere picture

[image: this sphere]

I'm not sure how to load shape files so if anyone can show some examples that would be nice.

Comment: When you speak about borders, do you mean country borders? Do you have the shape file of the borders for this globe view? In what graphical format is it? Have you already tried something yourself? What was the result?

Comment: @TomBrunberg yes i mean country boarders and yes i do have the shapefiles iuse firemonkey and i use viewport 3D and i couldnt find any tutorials for shapefiles in viewport

Comment: If you are looking for some Delphi/Pascal code for reading shape files. No problem, see here: https://osdn.net/projects/dzlib-tools/svn/view/dzlib/trunk/src/u_dzShapeFileReader.pas?view=markup&root=dzlib-tools But this only reads the files, it does not convert them to any kind of graphical output.